# Fragment Not Displaying In Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently when running my application, going to this activity does not display my fragment. Am I adding the fragment wrong and so nothing in the fragment is displayed? Or is there something wrong the dynamic behavior in the fragment `onCreateView` method?

### My Activity Code

```
public class AskQuestionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask_question);
    }
}
```

### My Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:hint="@string/header_text"/>
    <fragment android:name="com.mypackage.AskQuestionFragment"
              android:id="@+id/question_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### My Fragment Code

```
public class AskQuestionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String questionText = "What is your favorite color?";
        List<String> answers = Arrays.asList("Red", "Blue", "Yellow");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, container);
        Resources res = getResources();

        int id = res.getIdentifier("question_text", "id", layout.getContext().getPackageName());
        TextView questionTextView = (TextView)layout.findViewById(id);
        questionTextView.setText(questionText);

        id = res.getIdentifier("question_answers", "id", layout.getContext().getPackageName());
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)layout.findViewById(id);

        Collections.reverse(answers);
        for (String s : answers) {
            RadioButton button = new RadioButton(layout.getContext());
            button.setText(s);
            radioGroup.addView(button, 0);
        }

        return layout;
    }
}
```

### My Fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/question_container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/question_text"/>
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/question_answers"></RadioGroup>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit_button_text"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put framelayout instead of fragment in xml. and in your activity's onCreate create the instance of your fragment you want to display and add it to the fragment container

public class AskQuestionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask_question);

         AskQuestionFragment fragment =  new  AskQuestionFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.id_of_your_container, fragment).commit();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be when doing this:

`LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, container);`

Consider to replace that line with one of the following:

`LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);`

or

`LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, container, false);`

Answer (score 0):

change your layout from linear to be framelayout, and attach your fragment in activity .

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.your_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```